# Can't connect to site from VBA

Tags: vba, sharepoint, office365

I have this in VBA. I'm running Office 2016 32 bit in a windows 10 system. I'm attempting to connect to a sharepoint list to update it, but I can't log in. It's Office 365.

```
Dim sCnx As String
sCnx = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIDs=Yes;"
sCnx = sCnx & "DATABASE=https://bigCompany.com/sites/ISforAandP;"
sCnx = sCnx & "List={81D55769-42A0-4194-9561-ECBEC12A50D1};"

Dim cnx As ADODB.Connection
Set cnx = New ADODB.Connection
cnx.Open sCnx
```

The error I receive is "Invalid Argument".

I have searched thoroughly and unsuccessfully for help with this. Please help.

Thanks,

Dimas

Answer (score 0):

I have talked to the administrators of the SharePoint farm, and programmatic access is disabled, hence the error.

Comment: I will try downloading the link file and update it via Access. That's gotta do it by now.